# problem with .htaccess and mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My below .htaccess file should send everything to my `index.php` page where my framework [Fat Free Frameowkr] handles it.

However if I go to `http://www.site.com/` it works. If I go to `http://www.site.com/about` I get a 404 error.

Any ideas?

```
# Enable rewrite engine and route requests to framework
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]

# Disable ETags
Header Unset ETag
FileETag none

# Default expires header if none specified (stay in browser cache for 7 days)
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A604800
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I’m afraid that you need to do some further debugging (see [`RewriteLogLevel`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteloglevel)).

Comment: I setup `rewrite.log` but I get no error even with a high debug level. Just the 404.

Comment: Yes, but not sure what it was. something like ` # Enable rewrite engine and route requests to framework
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /fatfree/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /fatfree/index.php [L,QSA]
`

Answer (score 0):

Try this part

```
# Enable rewrite engine and route requests to framework
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

HTTP 404 links directly to case that your .htaccess haven't catch the request via .htaccess
so just for case check if you have .htaccess overriding allowed (httpd conf, [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride))